# JavaFx detect mouse movement (after reaching screen border)

Tags: java, javafx

I've created an image viewer that zooms in on mouse down and out on mouse released. While mouse down you can drag the image around:

```
public void dragOnMouseMove( MouseEvent event ) {

    if( zoomedIn ) {
        if( mouseStartX != null && mouseStartY != null ) {
            double x = this.getTranslateX() - (mouseStartX - event.getX());
            double y = this.getTranslateY() - (mouseStartY - event.getY());
            LOG.debug( "moving picture to: " + x + "," + y );
            this.setTranslateX( x );
            this.setTranslateY( y );
        }
        mouseStartX = event.getX();
        mouseStartY = event.getY();
    }
}
```

This is bound to drag event.
The problem is: when mouse reaches screen border the dragging stops because the coordinates are not more changing.
Is there a way to detect mouse movement independently of cursor position?

Comment: Maybe low level api mouse hook?

Comment: what? how? would you try to "answer"?

Comment: As long as the mouse is down, detect that you are at the screen border, and keep moving at constant speed. That speed should be computed by your previous values, but for a start you can define a constant speed.

Comment: no cause i need to detect when user stops moving mouse. the image to bee dragged is much bigger then the screen

Comment: @dermoritz Have you found a solution other than constant speed and guessing the direction? Because all questions i can find like https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3936820/how-to-detect-mouse-movement-beyond-screen-border are unanswered as well and the documentation doesn't help me much in this case.

Comment: @UmNyobe There would still be the problem of -what if it is already at the border , how to know the ANGLE OR DIRECTION OF THE MOVEMENT then-

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand you looking for a [MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html#getLocation%28%29) might be helpful. It returns a Point object corresponding to current mouse position.

Comment: no. i have the pointer's location. but if pointer reaches the border of screen (e.g. upper left corner) the location won't change anymore but i still want to detect that someone moves the mouse.

Comment: if MouseMotionListener nothing return, so I think it's not possible

Comment: @dermoritz OK i got my cursor pointer @ top left corner (0,0) - tell me, what do you want detect from there?

Comment: He would like recognition move the mouse when cursor is in corner <br>
for example: when cursor is in corner left top and user moving cursor in left still. <br>
This moving he'd detects